# angular-ui > ui-utils > ui-scroll does not work (v. 0.1.0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scrollbar, angular-ui, ui-scroll

I am using this: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/ and to be more specific this:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md

however it does not seem to work. Here is an example:

```
<div ng-scroll-viewport style="height:240px;" class="chat-messages">
                                <div class="chat-message" ng-scroll="chat in chats">
                                    <div ng-class="$index % 2 == 0? 'sender pull-right' : 'sender pull-left'">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <img src="{{chat.img}}" class="img-circle" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="time">
                                            {{chat.time}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-class="$index % 2 == 0? 'chat-message-body on-left' : 'chat-message-body'">
                                        <span class="arrow"></span>
                                        <div class="sender"><a href="#">{{chat.name}}</a></div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            {{chat.msg}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

But All I get in HTML is this :

```
<div class="chat">

    <div class="chat-messages" style="height:240px;" ng-scroll-viewport="">
        <!--

         ngScroll: chat in chats 

        -->
    </div>
```

If I replace ng-scroll with ng-repeat, it works perfectly. But chats need scroll bars, so... How can I get one? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting a scroll is to use CSS, set overflow-y to scroll and you will get scroll bar.

If you need to scroll to the bottom, play with anchorScroll
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of ngScroll directive had also tricked me into simply replacing ng-repeat by ng-scroll. Unfortunately, it turned out not as simple as that, see also the small, working example at http://plnkr.co/edit/fWhe4vBL6pevcuLutGC4 .

Note that

1. "datasource" (or whatever object you want to iterate over for the contents of the scroll list) must implement a method "get(index,count,success)" that calls success(results), see hXXps://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md#data-source
2. The array must have exactly count elements. Otherwise, no scroll window/bar will ever show, which can be very irritating!
3. Although UI.Utils says it has no external dependencies, ui.scroll has actually a dependency on either ui.scroll.jqlite, or jQuery. So make sure to list both ui.scroll and ui.scroll.jqlite in your module definition which contains the controller with datasource object (and load their .js files, or load ui-utils.js which contains both), see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md#dependencies
4. Be careful when your server is sending some Content Security Policies (CSP). Maybe turn them off while trying to get ng-scroll to work first, then re-apply CSP and tune the policies accordingly for ui.scroll to work.