# Need help creating a datasource object for AngularUI.util's ui-scroll directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I've got an array of objects that I would like to display in a scrollable window using an ng-repeat like structure in angular. So far I'm working with [Angular UI's utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) scroll bar.

I've read through the [read me](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md) and have also read through [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWhe4vBL6pevcuLutGC4?p=preview) given from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873894/angular-ui-ui-utils-ui-scroll-does-not-work-v-0-1-0) on a previous question on stack overflow. So in my code this is what I have currently, and it gives no errors when it runs, and it also doesn't display anything.

**In my module definition:**

```
var app = angular.module('PromoUI', ['ngRoute', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.scroll','ui.scroll.jqlite'])
```

**In my controller:**

```
    $scope.datasource = {
        get: function (index, count, success) {
            success($scope.discounts)
        }
    }
```

**In my view:**

```
    {{discounts[0].PromoCode}}
    <div ui-scroll-viewport style="height:300px">
      <div ui-scroll="discount in datasource">
        <p>{{discount.PromoCode}}</p>
        <p>{{discount.DiscountDescription}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(note above that {{discounts[0].PromoCode}} displays correctly in the browser)

**And my references are correct:**

```
  <!--ANGULAR UI-->
  <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-utils.js"></script>
```

I have a feeling I'm not setting up the datasource correctly. Could anyone out there who has used this directive give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have there may work as well, but I've set it up as follows:

```html
app.factory('datasource', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
      var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];
      var get = function (index, count, success) {
            return success(a);
        };
        return {
            get: get
        };
    }
]);
```

I have plnkr with this at http://plnkr.co/edit/W8Mzee

Comment: I forgot to mention that your datasource compiles with page load so if the $scope.discounts is not defined then, you will not see a thing.